# Is there a faster (less precise) algorithm than Levenshtein for string distance?

Tags: javascript, levenshtein-distance

I want to run the Levenshtein, but WAY faster because it's real time application that I'm building. It can terminate once the distance is greater than 10.

Comment: You're implementing "real-time" stuff in Javascript? Now I know better than most that JIT-compilers can do wonders, but aren't the people who write this kind of software usually very keen to know exactly what machine code runs so they can optimize the living hell out of it? (And that's not entirely unjustified, performance of JIT-compilers can be unpredictable and vary greatly and they can only beat statically-compiled hand-tuned C code in special curcumstances.)

Comment: Another vote for server-side Levenshtein. If you absolutely must do it in JavaScript, try Web Workers ( http://ejohn.org/blog/web-workers/ ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) metric allows addition, deletion or substitution operations. If you're looking for a faster but less precise metric you can use [the longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) (allows only addition and deletion) or even the [Hamming distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) (allows only substitution).

However, I recommend that you try to optimize your Levenshtein distance algorithm instead as it gives the best results.

Answer (score 7):

Judging from comments, people seem to be pretty happy with [Sift3](http://siderite.blogspot.com/2007/04/super-fast-and-accurate-string-distance.html).

http://sift.codeplex.com

Comment: For some reason it still returns 2 if you compare the same string to itself.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare UTF-8 contents use `sift4`:

https://siderite.dev/blog/super-fast-and-accurate-string-distance.html

Also I prepared a jsPerf which shows the performance difference between those libraries: http://jsperf.com/levenshtein-perf

Comment: is there a Python/Cython/C implementation for this algorithm to compare with Levenshtein method?

Comment: @GökhanSever Yes, see the linked page.

Comment: siderite.blogspot.com is gone, here is an archive link http://web.archive.org/web/20190613223908/https://siderite.blogspot.com/2014/11/super-fast-and-accurate-string-distance.html

Comment: I scanned the code of sift4 using the page provided by @amirouche, and the code works with "string"s which, AFAIK are utf-16 and NOT utf-8