# String similarity

Tags: javascript, string, similarity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [javascript text similarity Algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5042873/javascript-text-similarity-algorithm)

I'd like to know whether there is any library, in JavaScript, to measure the **similarity** of two strings (like "john" and "Johhn"). In postgresql I'm using the [pg_trgm](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgtrgm.html) module,  which works with trigrams. I'd like to know what is available in JavaScript.

The only one found so far is [one](http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/levenshtein/) based on the Levenshtein distance.

Comment: Did you check [this plugin](https://gist.github.com/1562394)? It's quite simple to implement just as a plain JS function; jQuery is used just for convenience.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex is what you are looking for.

Comment: @raina77ow: interesting, thank you

Comment: @jbabey: thanks, however the implementations linked from there seem to be wrong (from the desc)

Comment: see also this question about levenshtein: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178708/is-there-a-faster-less-precise-algorithm-than-levenshtein-for-string-distance its an algorithm for calculating the distance of two strings